# Champion Selection (With Randoms) What should I do?

Tags: league-of-legends

When I go into solo-queue I get paired with a number of randoms who insta-lock their characters like they don't know how to play anyone else... I usually try to pick based on what the team needs, but I was wondering if I should communicate more with the team before-hand so that I know what is going through their minds when they choose their champions.

For example, say you're sitting in Champ Select and you have an AP mid, a bot support, a strong AD tank top and a Tristana. Seeing that the group may need more magic damage, you lock in a strong AP champion. After the loading screen and everyone is their lanes, the Tristana says "ap trist" and the support turned out to be playing "ap carry Lulu." So, now your team has 4 AP champions, the enemy stacks MR and focuses your solo top. gg wp.

Should I communicate with team more or start playing hybrid champs to adapt to any situation or should I just abandon all hope and get together a strong pre-made group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to go premade with people you know.

If you solo then yes you should ask people what builds are they using and what lanes they want to be in,people will often be ok and tell you how they plan to play the game,but of course there are times when you just get people that want to troll and there is nothing you can do about it.

Personally what i sometimes do when i enter solo queue is that i type in:"STOP DON'T LOCK IN" as soon as i enter queue,and people often listen and do not lock it after that,and then i tell them that we should build our team carefully and most people are ok with that.
Of course some people get rude about it and lock in with random champion and there is nothing you can do about them,either dodge queue or stick with them and hope for the best.

I would also mention that even if you get really weird team combination that you can still win if you're lucky.Even if your team may have crappy combination there is a chance that enemy team doesn't have good combination either or that they don't know how to play their champions so good.So there is always hope.

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your own question. Unless you know these are people who know what they're doing (ranked), ask them to be clear. Most people should declare where they're going.

Answer (score 1):

In blind pick normal, you can try to communicated, but I agree that does little hope as if a random wants to troll they will and you can't do anything about it.  In draft mode, your team should communicate with each other but sadly it doesn't always happen.  Just try your best and hope for the best.  Even a team with all AP champs can win, for instance when they face a team of all AD champs.

BTW, in general, even if the support Lulu stayed as support, your team still pretty much has 4 champs that do AP based damage and 1 AD damage.  Additionally, if the enemy team focuses your AD tank top, that means they are focusing the tank, which should mean that they are not focusing the actual carries but the tank.  I know this is not the intention of your post, but wanted to point out how it is NEVER GG WP just from champ select, even if some like the trist was doing an alternate build that would be considered trolling by many.